# check ethernet connection periodically android

Tags: android, android-networking, icmp, network-connection

I'm trying to periodically check the network connection. However, this is for a Chinese Android Mini PC, not a tablet or smartphone. I'm using an *ethernet to usb adapter* instead of Wi-Fi. First I used a broadcastreceiver class:

```
public class NetworkStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            NetworkInfo eni = (NetworkInfo) intent.getExtras().get(
                    ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

            if (eni != null && eni.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Network " + eni.getTypeName() + " connected.");
            }
        }
        if (intent.getExtras().getBoolean(
                ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, Boolean.FALSE)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "There's no network connectivity.");
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly for Wi-Fi and mobile. However, for ethernet, there are complications. When I connect the *ethernet to usb adapter*, it thinks it **already** has ETHERNET connection, **whether the ethernet cable is connected or not**. Only when removing the adapter, it knows the ethernet connection was removed.

I tried using a socket, and this kind of works:

```
    private static boolean checkSocket(String host, int port) {
        Socket socket = null;
        boolean reachable = false;
        try {
            socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(host), port);
            reachable = true;
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        } finally {
            if (socket != null) {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        }
        return reachable;
    }
```

When there is a connection, it works perfectly and fast. When the connection is lost, it takes way too long for the program to know it has. I need this solution, but it should know **way faster** that the ethernet connection has been lost. Also, this relies on Exceptions, which I'm not fond of at all.

Lastly I tried a simple ICMP message:

```
    try {
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
        if (address.isReachable(timeout)) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    return false;
```

This *should* work, right? Unfortunately, it doesn't. Until now, I've always received a `false` when executing this code.

What am I doing wrong and what is the correct way to do this?

**EDIT 1**

I have now tried this solution, which works and doesn't work. It's funny and annoying, as I'm checking this in the `onResume()`. After a few correct tries, it suddenly stops. I have no idea why though.

```
    boolean reachable = false;
    try {
        Process p1 = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -c 1 " + host);
        int retValue = p1.waitFor();
        reachable = (retValue == 0);
        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(reachable));
        p1.destroy();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return reachable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting to ip addres, not resolving dns as you do

ADD:
Try using [ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getActiveNetworkInfo%28%29) then

```
((ConnectivityManager) Context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()
```

Comment: That makes no difference, as expected though.

Comment: Hm. Maybe ConnectivityManager will help you: http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html